# Does requestIdleCallback work in the background page of Chrome extensions?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can't find any documentation on this one way or another. The function `window.requestIdleCallback` does exist in a Chrome extension's background page. But when I run

```
window.requestIdleCallback(() => {
  console.log("XXX idle");
});
```

The callback appears to never run. Is this intended behavior, or is there something that could be causing the callback to never run here?

A bit more information: the manifest does have `{"persistent": true}` set. And the `window.requestIdleCallback` function does exist, it just doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: If your background page is an event page ("persistent": false), it won't work because the page will unload. Not sure if it will work if you make it persistent.

Comment: This function is frame-based just like rAF so it doesn't work in a nonrenderable context such as the background page.

Comment: I am not sure if `requestIdleCallback` is a function in Chrome since I can't find it in the [Chrome API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows), instead I found [this one](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/08/using-requestidlecallback) whom uses this function. Have you tried to check this?